# Install XP on SATA drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, bsod, sata, windows-installation

So I’ve been trying to install Windows XP on my HP Pavilion dv6-6c48us laptop, which uses a SATA drive, and so far I have not been successful. I’ve tried slipstreaming uniata drivers http://alter.org.ua/soft/win/uni_ata/ but either I’m not doing this correctly, or it’s just not compatible with my hardware, because it BSODs after the setup loads. I’ve already tried using VMware, but the 3D acceleration is too slow on XP for the things I want to do. Is there a way to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: You've said in the comments that it's an NVMe drive, but your title says it's SATA. Which one is it?

Comment: The laptop I want to install XP on is SATA. The discussion below is about VMware, which I have on my desktop. My original post is about the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

XP is not compatible with this newer hardware. It does not have the correct drivers.

> I’ve already tried using VMware, but the 3D acceleration is too slow
> on XP for the things I want to do.

I have XP here using VMware Workstation and it works very well. VMware. 3D Acceleration is ON and it is not too slow. You can try this setting either way.

What are you trying to run in XP that this setup is too slow for?

Make sure you are using the newest version of VMware Workstation and that VMware Tools have been installed (important for video). The Video Memory on my XP Machine is 256 MB which should handle most things.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that even with slipstreamed drivers XP will not install? Yes, I’m using an M.2 NVMe drive, the application is an old 3D bowling game called HyperBowl and it lags a lot, especially when playing in a larger level.

Comment: Yes.  XP is an ancient system and there is no way I know to make it work with newer hardware like this. The last machine I saw that would run XP was from 2008.

Comment: So uniata is pretty much useless for my purposes then?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  If the game is old , it should run in an XP virtual machine.

Comment: It does, but like I said it lags. I’m assuming it may have something to do with my CPU or the fact that the SVGA II driver will only recognize 128 MB of VRAM.

Comment: According to the game’s website stored on archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20040409183631/http://hyperbowl.com/support/home-game-support.html the game requires a minimum of 16 MB VRAM, so I guess part of my assumption is wrong.

Comment: I amended my answer to remove the question about disk drive since you answer that. But my own VM has 256 MB of memory.

Comment: Superuser is recommending that this discussion should be moved to a chat, would that be better?

Comment: You can move the comments to chat to see what other ideas are there.

Comment: Apparently, I don’t have enough reputation, so I can’t. Anyway, I’m using VMware player 16 and I don’t remember seeing anything about aspect ratios or stretching the display, which would be a useful feature. That’s a separate issue though. EDIT: If you open dxdiag with Win+R and click Display, it shows only 128 MB, despite my VRAM being set to 1 GB.

Comment: If you really wish to run this game, you can try VMware Workstation (better than Player). You can install a trial version (30 days I think) and import the XP Machine to VMware Workstation and see if it works better this way.

Comment: I think I’ll try that out. If I still have problems, I’ll come back to this discussion. Thanks.

Comment: I tried using workstation, and it improved the performance. It still lags though.

Comment: I am not sure. I wonder if it is a timing issue in the game. You may need to find an older computer (slower), or that game may past its time.

Comment: Well, at least workstation pro fixed the display stretching issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Perhaps you can mark my post as the answer now.